# How to mock Laravel models properly?

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

There is a case where I gotta create a user record in another user table, using the main User object, then when the User2 record is done, update its username field appending its id. (don't ask about why, cuz I don't know)
Anyway, I have extremely hard time testing it.  I am trying to mock with mocking User and then User2 and calling `expects($this->once())->method('save')->willReturn(true)` . But then I get errors like the `generateUser2Username` function should have received a string ($user->name) , but it received null. For that I tried the `$mockUser->expects($this->once())->method('__name')->willReturn('Joe Bloggs')` but then it threw error that it couldn't call the 'email' magic function on the mocked $user object.

I am also unsure if I inject a mock User object or a proper User object into the invoke function.

Ideally what I'd want to test:

- generateUser2Username ( I know its private, but can I test it on the $user2mock object after this ran ? )
- User2::create function has been called with `$user2Username, $this->user->email, self::A_USER_TYPE`
- User2::save function has been called.
- User::save function has been called.
- User->user2_id is set to User2->id

I just got exhausted trying to sort this out.

ps. the private methods have to stay private.

```
namespace App\Page\Actions;

use App\User;
use App\Models\Shops\User2;
use Exception;

class CreateUser2ForUserAction
{
    const A_USER_TYPE = 3;

    /**
     * @var User
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * @param User $user
     * @return User
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function __invoke(User $user): User
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $user2username = $this->generateUser2Username($this->user->name);

        $User2 = $this->createUser2(
            $user2Username,
            $this->user->email,
            self::A_USER_TYPE
        );

        $this->updateUser2UsernameWithId($User2);
        $this->updateUserUser2Id($user2->id);


        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @return string
     */
    private function generateUser2Username(string $name): string
    {
        $names = explode(' ', $name);
        return substr($names[0], 0, 3) . substr($names[1], 0, 3);
    }

    /**
     * @param string $user2Username
     * @param string $email
     * @param int $userType
     * @return User2
     */
    private function createUser2(string $user2Username, string $email, int $userType): User2
    {
        return User2::create(
            [
                'username' => $user2Username,
                'email' => $email,
                'user_type' => $userType
            ]
        );
    }

    /**
     * @param User2 $user2
     * @return void
     * @throws Exception
     */
    private function updateUser2UsernameWithId(User2 $User2): void
    {
        $user2->username = $user2->username . $user2->id;
        $success = $user2->save();

        if (!$success) {
            throw new Exception("We couldn't update User2.username");
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param int $user2Id
     * @return void
     * @throws Exception
     */
    private function updateUserUser2Id(int $user2Id): void
    {
        $this->user->user2_id = $user2Id;
        $success = $this->user->save();

        if (!$success) {
            throw new Exception("We couldn't update User.user2_id");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you any updates for this? Did you try anything else? Please, try to make some updates to this question, in order to be more approachable for the reader to understand and give an answer.

Comment: hey,
thanks for reaching out. 
I actually ended up having to use integration tests with Faker. Because this is an action that triggers a database2.user creation when database1.user is created. So I couldn't find a way to mock it properly because ultimately if I mock the Eloquent models behaviour (db1.User and db2.User), there's gonna be nothing else to test. 

At the end I ended up not mocking behaviour but using factories and a setUp(), tearDown() with db::rollback() to get rid of the created records after test. 
Let me know if this is enough or not :)